# How to shrink and fit any logo in a fixed box

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website over at http://notice.byethost12.com . I have finished most of the work but I am getting problems in making any logo appear resize to fit in the grid for them. So are tall while some are wide. and if not most are just stretch. I am pretty new with this. So I'd be glad if you could help.

Comment: No idea what you've already tried but a good place to start: `img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto}`

Comment: post an example, give us your problem. Don't just post a random link say this no work, fix ty. SO is not a free coding service nor a tutorial website

Comment: You can try to set `background-size: contain;  background-repeat: no-repeat;` on `.thumbnail-image` class.

Comment: @DhavalChheda yes the website is in php and wordpress

Comment: @N.Ivanov Sorry I didnt specifically know which files to provide you with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're using a background image in your `thumbnail-image` class, you'll need to specify `background-size` and `background-repeat` rules.

Add this to your css:

```
.thumbnail-image {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Probably because you need more specificity in your selectors, e.g: `.grid-plus-container .post-item .thumbnail-image {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}`